# Customizing Texmaker

Tags: configuration, programming, customization, source-code

I use LaTeX a lot but I find quite obnoxious all the crappy files it leaves behind when you compile: .aux, .log...

Fortunately TeXMaker has the option "clean" that deletes all of these.

However, I don't like having to remember to click on it every time I'm going to close a document, ie I'd like a button that both closes a document and cleans all that stuff.

Any hint as how to do it? I suppose if I knew how to access the program code I'd be able to do it as I'd just have to put together two options that already exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the menu:

Options → Configure → QuickBuild → User
and define there (in User) the actions that you want by specifying the command pipeline.

For example, I have the following pipeline:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | bibtex %.aux | bibtex %.aux | bibtex %.aux | 
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | 
dvipdf %.dvi | rm %.aux %.bbl %.blg %.dvi %.log %.out %.toc
```

Note that at the end of the pipe, I removed files specifying them by their extension (.toc, .aux, etc)

Hope it helps.

Comment: note that texmaker complains about the missing log file, so I removed the `%.log` from the command above. Keeping the log file around also means you can more easily troubleshoot errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what worked best for me was to compile TexMaker from source merging the methods to clean and to close. So any time I close a file the auxiliary files are removed.